document.execCommand and document.queryCommandState doesn't work in Svelte
I want to create a text editor, but there are some confusing problems that have come up :

The text formatting doesn't work unless text is selected first
The color change on the buttons when the formatting is active sometimes works and sometimes doesn’t. I’ve tried three methods : wrapping it in a function didn’t work, adding an arrow function () => in the onClick makes the color appear active even before I click, and when I do click, it doesn’t change. Using document.queryCommandState directly without wrapping in a function didn’t work either.

And is using bind:innerHTML as I did safe for security? If it’s not safe, what is the safe way?
<script>
    function formatText(command){
        document.execCommand(command, false, null);
    }
    
    function isFormatActive(command){
        return document.queryCommandState(command);
    }
</script>

<div class="bg-black text-white font-lg font-bold">
    <button class:bg-emerald-950={isFormatActive("italic")} on:click={() => formatText("italic")} class="p-4">
        <i>I</i>
    </button>
    <button class:bg-emerald-950={() => isFormatActive('bold')} on:click={() => formatText('bold')} class="p-4">
        <b>B</b>
    </button>
    <button class:bg-emerald-950={document.queryCommandState('underline')} on:click={() => formatText('underline')} class="p-4">
        <u>U</u>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="bg-emerald-500 text-white p-4 rounded-lg focus:border-none focus:outline-none" contenteditable="true">hello</div>


document.execCommand and document.queryCommandState are Deprecated: This feature is no longer recommended

Ah I didn't know it >< What are the alternative of them?

I wouldn't have the first clue

I dont understand what do you mean, my english is not good ><

I mean that I do not know what you need to use. I could research it, but then, so could you.

Ah ok, thank you for your answers, I have found an alternative that is using selection and range api but I'm looking for if there is simpler one alternative

These functions are not reactive, you have to make sure that the function is executed on every selection change.
This can be done by e.g. listening to the selectionchange event and making isFormatActive dependent on a key that is changed when the selection is changed.
<script>
    let selectionKey = {};

    function formatText(command) {
        document.execCommand(command, false, null);
    };

    $: isFormatActive = command => {
        selectionKey; // dependency
        return document.queryCommandState(command);
    };

    function onSelectionChange() {
        selectionKey = {};
    }
</script>

<svelte:document on:selectionchange={onSelectionChange} />

...
<button class:bg-emerald-950={isFormatActive("italic")} ...

REPL
You may want to restrict the setting of the key to only happen if the selection change happened within the text editor element. document.getSelection() will give you the current selection.

There is 1 problem with that code, if I click the formatting buttons without selecting any text then typing some words, the results are sometime the formatting and the active color work and sometime not work. And I modify the code by removing the selectionchange event and replacing it by calling onSelectionChange() inside formatText() function after document.execCommand(), it gives the same functionality in selecting a text first before clicking the button without listening to event, but it fails at the same problem that I mentioned above. Do you have any idea to solve the problem?

This is not really valid without a selection. Maybe handle that case separately.

Can you give any idea what is needed to handle the without selection case?

No, I also think it's outside the scope of this question. You probably first need to determine what happens e.g. if the cursor is between a bold and non-bold section and then act accordingly. Personally, I would not try to implement an editor from scratch at all, it's extremely complicated; there are libraries for that. (It's also hard to get the accessibility right if you are not already an expert in the field.)

I think determining if the cursor in a bold section or not can be obtained from the queryCommandState(), in my analysis it needs to insert <b></b> in the cursor position when the user start typing and also getting the current innerHTML content of the cursor position then if it contains <b> the <b></b> tag is removed, correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm still looking for how to get the innerHTML. Thank you for your answers

Have you searched? There should be questions about this already, maybe this one.

Yeah I have tried the methods of the answers in the article above from another article, it didn't return the innerHTML but it returned the text string with no HTML, I have just copied the code in the article above but it resulted the same, it returned the string text only
